# Is there a way to stop monit from sending monitor and unmonitor email messages

Tags: monit

I've recently started using `Monit` to monitor some production machines.  And it does this well.  But the annoying issue I have is that part of the routine is to restart the servers once a day on a rotating basis and each of those restarts generates a `unmonitor` and `monitor` message.

I can't find a specific `alert` setting to turn this off and consequently I'm bombarded by correct but unnecessary messages.  There does not seem to be a specific event related to this.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  To be clear, I want to tell monit to unmonitor a server/task, restart or do something, then restart the server/task, then monitor it again.  But I don't want to know about the unmonitor or monitor, only failure situations.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable alerts for user actions in general, like the `monitrc` states:

```
## Do not alert when Monit starts, stops or performs a user initiated action.
## This filter is recommended to avoid getting alerts for trivial cases.
#
# set alert your-name@your.domain not on { instance, action }
```

Documentation: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-event-filter